# How to get a new dataframe out of non-repeating items from other dataframes (Python Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Let's suppose I have two dataframes:

```
df1:
     0    1    
0    A    A
1    A    B
2    A    D

df2:
     0    1
0    A    C
1    A    A
2    A    D
```

What I want is to take every item that is contained by only one of the dataframes and create a new dataframe out of it:

```
df3:
     0    1
0    A    B
1    A    C
```

Line 0 (df1) and line 1 (df2), as well as line 2 of both exist in both dataframes, and therefore are excluded.

I tried doing this with the following code:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False, subset=1)
```

However, after that, df3 returns an empty dataframe. What did I do wrong? Is the subset the problem?

Comment: Yes just remove the `subset=1`

Comment: The given code works for me, can't reproduce.